# how to delete a selected node from dnd container by passing the DnDitem id?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want some thing like this to happen...

```
 function(){
    this.dndContiner=new Source("someId");
    this.dndContiner.insertNodes(false,{somenode});
    },
    function(DNDItemId){
    this.dndContiner.getNode(DNDItemId).deleteSelectedNodes();
    }
```

please help.. not finding any solution for it.

Comment: i want actually to remove a dndItem from Container ..i have only with be the id of the item .

Comment: this.dndContiner.getNode(DNDItemId).deleteSelectedNodes();like this some thing i need but its not there instead some other option please help